# Why is line voltage used to find base impedance of transformer if the L equivalent circuit is single phase?

Tags: power, transformer

If in an equivalent circuit of a transformer, such as this one:

[image]

Which is single-phase, why do we use phase-to-phase voltage to find the base impedance (given the apparent power)? Why not phase-neutral voltage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm assuming the system is three-phase, just to make sense. So the formula is:
$$Z=\frac{V_{l}^2}{S_{3f}}$$
Note the power is the sum of the three-phses. You can also make the computation using the phase-to-ground voltage, but then you will have to use the single-phase power.
$$Z=\frac{V_{p}^2}{S_{1f}}$$
Since:
$$V_{l}=\sqrt{3}\ V_{p}$$
and:
$$S_{3f}=3\ S_{1f}$$

Both will give the same results.

Answer (score 0):

> *why do we use phase-to-phase voltage to find the base impedance (given
> the apparent power)? Why not phase-neutral voltage?*

You use precisely the voltage that is applied to the primary (be it phase-neutral or phase-phase). Your diagram doesn't indicate what V1 is so, it's open to interpretation. Nevertheless, you must use the right voltage.